# A compact set K contained in $(0,∞)$ and a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in K that converges to 0.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

**Give an example or argue that it is impossible.**

I argue that it is impossible because, if $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence which converges to 0, then $(x_n)_n$ must be bounded above or below by 0. As $(x_n)_n$ is in K, then the set K must have the element 0 which is false as K is in the open interval of $(0,∞)$.

This is my argument. I am not sure if this is the right argument or the right way to express it.

Comment: Codelearner. You may want to look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227395/relationship-between-sequences-and-closed-sets

Answer (score 2):

Compactness is not needed only the fact that $K$ is closed: if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in a closed set that converges to $\ell$, then $\ell$ belongs to said closed set.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue as follows: since $K $ is compact, every sequence in $K $ has a convergent subsequence with the limit in $K$. Now, as $(x_n)$ converges to  $0$, so does every subsequence of $(x_n)$. But $0\notin K $.